# Please let me know what is the difference between cd bin and cd $bin?

Tags: linux

If we use `cd` bin, we should able to navigating to bin folder.

then what is the purpose of using `$` before bin directory?
"`cd $bin_dir`"

Please explain me

Answer (score 0):

$bin_dir is environment variable (read here for more information - [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)), say $bin_dir is declared like `export bin_dir=/usr/local/bin`, than your command `cd $bin_dir` is equal to `cd /usr/local/bin`.